# Interface typed parameter controller action not called from UI/jquery ajax in MVC JSON input

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, interface

I have problem of action has not been called due to interface typed parameter (calling from UI client side scripting ajax)

**Controller:** TestController

**Error Action** (because of interface type parameter): UpdateUserInfomation(**IInputParam** paramObj) {Doing some stuff with the help of paramObj}

**Without Error Action** (because of concrete type paramter): UpdateUserInfomation(**InputParam** paramObj) {Doing some stuff with the help of paramObj}

Concrete type parameter then there is no issue when we chnage it interface typed parameter then action is not fired.

Below is the code snippet

```
public interface IInputParam
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    DateTime BirthDt { get; set; }
    string Language { get; set; }
}

public partial class InputParam: IInputParam
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDt { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

```js
// Data cook
var data = {
    FirstName:$(firstName).val(),
    LastName:$(firstName).val(),
    BirthDt:$(firstName).val(),
    Language:$(firstName).val()
}

// Call controller action from UI (client side scripting)
$.ajax({
    url: URL pointing to controller/action (~/TestController/UpdateUserInfomation),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ paramObj: data }),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success == true) {
            alert("called and came fine");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an instance of an interface.  MVC has to be able to create an instance of whatever type the parameters of the action are.  So you can't use an interface for an action parameter.

You could either use InputParam for the action parameter or you could change IInputParam to a class that InputParam inherits from.

Comment: Then what is use of dependency injection or IOC and how its been implemented?

Comment: Those are design patterns that do have uses.  There are plenty of resources out there that talk about how and when to use them.  As for MVC actions, you have to use instantiable types.  You could have multiple actions that take classes that implement IInputParams and then pass them to a function that has a parameter of type IInputParams.